# Require is not defined in console. node.js js mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

I am trying to pass some coordinates from mysql database to be marked on a map but am having trouble getting them. i have looked at a number of similar questions on stackoverflow and have not been able to find an answer. Would appreciate if someone could please point out where i have gone wrong.

getListings.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'xx',
  port: 'xxxx',
};

var connection = mysql.createConnection(config); 
connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error connecting:' + err.stack);
  }
  console.log('connected successfully to DB.');

  connection.query('SELECT listing_coords FROM listings', (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
    var results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
    module.exports = { results };
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

Then in my script.js file i have

```
var { results } = require('./getListings');
      console.log(results);
```

I am getting an error in the browser console saying "require is not defined"

I will need to figure out how to pull the coordinates from mysql in order to plot them, there has to be a way? Do i have to build an api and use ajax? Thanks in advance for any help.

have updated my getListings.js file - it now displays in the string of data i need in the browser as a raw data packet

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json());

config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'xx',
  port: 'xxxx',
};

var connection = mysql.createConnection(config); //added the line
connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error connecting:' + err.stack);
  }
  console.log('connected successfully to DB.');

  app.listen(5000, () => console.log('express server is running at 5000'));

  app.get('/listings', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(
      'SELECT listing_coords FROM listings',
      (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err) res.send(rows);
        else console.log(err);
      }
    );
  });
```

I have been unsuccessful to get the output to run in script.js. I will post the working code when its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I got to work is as follows:

getListings.js (this was nodeJS)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());

**app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  next();
});**// I believe this is a middleware function

config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'xx',
  port: 'xxxx',
};

var connection = mysql.createConnection(config); //added the line
connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error connecting:' + err.stack);
  }
  console.log('connected successfully to DB.');
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('express server is running at 5000'));// this can be any port that isnt currently in use

app.get('/listings', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(
    'SELECT listing_coords FROM listings',
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (!err) res.send(rows);
      else console.log(err);
    }
  );
});
```

in my script.js file i was missing the following

```
      $.get('http://localhost:5000/listings', function (data, status) {
        console.log('Cords Data', data);
```

I believe that is the jQuery ajax

Then in the heading of my html I needed the following

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "module" defer src="script.js"></script>
```

thanks to everyone that helped me with this. especially @tsecheukfung01.

I dont fully understand all of the pieces so it will take me a while to fully understand this and be able to recreate this on my own. All part of the journey!

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting an error ***in the browser*** console saying "require is not defined"

It is because `require` is not an API for frontend. It should be the syntax of backend(eg. nodeJS).

> Do i have to build an api and use ajax?

If you wanna to send data from frontend to backend. Using `ajax` is possible but the main point is you need to have a backend server(eg. using `Express` module for nodeJS) to connect with the database(eg. mysql, postgresSQL).

---

**Update on 14 Feb, 2021**

My practise for doing this is to use `ajax` to send a request to the backend server from frontend.

```
//frontend
$.ajax
  ({
    url: "yourBackendServerUrl", //eg. localhost:8001/listing. Need modification based on your backend setting.
  })
  .done(function(data) {
     console.log(data)  //data should be the result from backend, then you can retrieve the data for frontend usage
});
```

For the CORS problem, you can install `cors` package. If you have a middleware in the global scope(a.k.a. `app.use(cors())` ). Every time there are request, this middleware will run.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors()) // pay attention to this line of code. 
 
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: Thank you. the code above is successfully retrieving the coordinates from the server, the console.log(results) in getListings.js is a string of the coordinates array in the myql table, however it is only showing in the terminal. I would like to call that in the script.js file, use it and then display it in an index.php. Is the module.exports = {results}; part of the code correct? what should i be using instead of var { results } = require('./getListings');   in the script.js file? i have tried some import functions but they dont seem to work at all. I will look in to ajax more.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I tried that code and am getting "origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." I have played around with the getListings.js file and have included an API that is displaying a string in the browser now, which I think is a step in the right direction! but I am still unable to get it to get the output in to the script.js  file for usage.

Comment: @walkslowly So you now have an ```express``` backend server right? For the CORS problem, you can install ```cors``` package for this problem. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @walkslowly I saw you edit and I have seen you have come up with a workable solution. I suggest you can answer your own question by posting your edit as a new answer and ticking it. If my help does help, you can upvote my answer :)). Glad to help